# Why does a cURL request return international pages (eg. Google Search)?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to perform a cURL request (either directly from shell or via PHP) that will return a URL's content essentially the same as the request made through a browser (minus any cookies/logins, etc).

A basic cURL request for *www.google.com* will return what appears to be the Japanese version of Google Search with some character encoding issues.

Testing with the options including setting a standard User Agent and follow location still does not result in what I assumed would be a very similar request to my browser. Is there a set of flags I should be using to closely imitate a browser request?

The code below is currently used for testing, but even with cookies being stored Google assumes the location is Japan (google.co.jp).

```
$header = array(
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5",
        "Connection: keep-alive",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
    );
$useragent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Could be a lack of cookies when curling? Perhaps Google stores some cookies on your PC to know what locality you are from, and gives you the correct Google site from this

Comment: Please post the code you are using.

Comment: I have included my current testing code in the question, thanks @cryptic

Comment: @Rhys, where is your server located? I know for a fact that Google will serve different languages when it detects an IP address comes from a certain country. It's kinda annoying when you have to use a proxy on browser, and say use a proxy from China it will serve the Chinese version of Google. I am sure that is your problem. Your server is located in that region and Google is detecting it as that, thus will serve the appropriate language.

Comment: You need to use a proxy located in the US preferably to get it to not do that.

Comment: Of course, @cryptic! Now I feel stupid. Yes my datacenter is running out of Tokyo, although rather than a proxy I think it would be better to move locations.

Comment: @Rhys, that's also an option =oP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$header = array(
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5",
        "Connection: keep-alive",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
    );
$useragent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'PROXY_IP_HERE:PROXY_PORT'); // Use a proxy located in USA
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```